# Haskell GHC mod error in Atom

Tags: haskell, ide, atom-editor, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

I'm trying to set up a [Haskell IDE](https://atom-haskell.github.io/) with [Atom](https://atom.io/) on mac. I install the binaries with [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) and make sure the right paths are under "Additional Path Directories", but get the following errors from [GHC mod](https://atom.io/packages/haskell-ghc-mod):

[image]

I also tried using cabal instead of stack, with the same result.

Comment: What path did you provide exactly? Which packages did you install, `ide-haskell` or `ide-haskell-cabal`?